# How to create a custom setting file for vscode extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are developing a new vscode extension, currently all workspace configuration contributed are kept in `settings.json` file in `.vscode` directory. We would like to keep all the configuration(settings) related to the new extension in a separate file in `.vscode` directory.

Is there way to do this?

All features that vscode settings page provides, should also be supported, like auto-suggestions of configuration keys, setting form etc.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea...

Comment: In our extension, we will be having large number of configuration, so we prefer not to clutter the default file. Same behaviour is also see in popular extensions like microsoft cpp